# Why is SQL developer ID column return me BigDecimal instead of simple integer?

Tags: sql-server, ruby, sequel-gem

I'm using the sequel gem to read a SQL server database table.

Before I do that, I connect to the SQL server database using Oracle SQL developer, and the id column shows 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

The table definition looks like this in SQL Developer:
[image]

But when I use the sequel gem to read the table in Ruby, that ID column is a BigDecimal and shows something like 0.1e1. Why is this? If this is an ID, shouldn't it always be integer?

How am I expected to use this field? Am I supposed to call to_i on it to convert it to integer?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but what is the underlying column type?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I am trying to access the Microsoft SQL server, but I am reading it by using the SQL developer provided by Oracle.

Comment: @CriticalError The underlying data type is numeric with 10 precision as displayed in the image. I don't know if that caused the 0.1e1 expression in Ruby but the Oracle SQL developer display 1 instead of 0.1e1. I don't understand why this discrepancy exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NUMERIC` value on your database is actually a non-integer type. You have a numeric scale here of 0, as in "no decimal part" but it's still considered a `BigDecimal` by Ruby with, as on the database, no decimal part.

If you have an integer type, like `INT`, then you'll get an Integer in Ruby, but only if. This column could be represented by `INT(10)` but it isn't and until you make that alteration Sequel will respect that difference.

It does seem extraordinarily unusual to have a `NUMERIC` type identifier. That's probably a mistake.